Some kind of Mark Joshi memorium?
Can this community find something appropriate to do in memorium of the passing of one of its strongest contributors?  Mark Joshi died of a heart attack last month.  See  https://www.wilmott.com/memoriam-professor-mark-joshi/

Didn't know. That's very sad...

Mark was a contributor on Quant.SE. Here is his profile.

@bobjansen I reached out via chat and in the answer below with ideas from our developers of what we might be able to do in terms of a memorial to Mark but haven't received much feedback. When the mods and community are ready to weigh in with their ideas feel free to put this back into status-review and we'd be happy to pick this up again.

One thing that could be attempted is to have a small nod (a hat tip?) to him or Easter egg in the customized design for this site, if and when we get it.
I don’t know whether that is feasible or appreciated but it might be worth a try.

It seems BT have taken his site down now, you can still view it on the wayback machine here.

Has there ever been any progress made on this? Easter Egg or something like that would indeed be a nice commemoration!

I tagged for staff attention.

Have we ever made any progress on this? I think it's still worth pursuing, particularly as time goes by, one realizes how significant Mark Joshi's contribution has been to the quant community.

Thank you for status-reviewing this Bob so that it came to our attention. I think it would be lovely to find a fitting tribute to Mark.
We had a few ideas that have come up internally

We could potentially do a small "easter egg" somewhere on the site to have a line about Mark, a quote of his, possibly an image somewhere. We'd your thoughts about what you'd have in mind there.
We aren't able to currently build a new custom page but we could customize the 404 page to mention him, if that feels appropriate, that might not be the right space but I wanted to throw that out since it's an option.
The moderators on sites have the ability to customize site tour and add a line about Mark to the end of the tour.

Let me know if any of these seem like options that would be fitting or that your community would be interested in. Also please do comment if you have alternative ideas. We'll see what's feasible but we'd love to help you get a fitting tribute to Mark in place.

Easter Egg sounds great!

I like the Easter Egg idea too. Does anyone have ideas for quotes, lines, etc that would be a meaningful way to honor Mark?

RIP Mark. He was excellent contributor. There must be something the community will surely do to reward his presence there. I guess you should have written to the community what your ideas are about and let people sign some petition that will be heard by the community.

I did not know, it is indeed a very sad news, but what do you suggest?
